# Effective Rate for this balloon payment

Tags: interest

Need some help on this calculation:

Loan Amount:  $377100

Down payment:  $41900

Monthly payment:  $5998

Balloon payment at the end:  $206540

Tenor:  36 months

I want to know how to calculate the effective interest rate.  Can anyone give me an answer?  I am using Casio F100 Financial Calculator, please teach me how to use this calculator to calculate this.

Comment: Appreciate for all reply. So the conclusion is by our manual calculation, the effective interest rate is 11.063%, also the same as automated webpage calculator, right?

Comment: No, the effective rate is 5.22% as shown in the webpage calculator screenshot below.

Answer (score 1):

The value of the loan is equal to the sum of the discounted values of the repayments.

[image]

```
∴ b = ((1 + r) (m + (1 + r)^n (r s - m)))/r

and m = (r ((1 + r)^(1 + n) s - b))/((1 + r) ((1 + r)^n - 1))
```

where

```
s = present value of loan
m = periodic repayment
r = periodic rate
b = balloon payment
n = number of periods (or payments) before the balloon
```

There is no formula for the periodic rate `r`.  You will need to solve for it using one of the above equations.

```
s = 377100
m = 5998
b = 206540
n = 35
```

Solving `s = (m - m (1 + r)^-n)/r + b/(1 + r)^(n + 1)` for `r`

```
∴ r = 0.00372937
```

So the effective annual rate is `(1 + r)^12 - 1 = 4.56819 %`

This assumes [full amortisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balloon_payment_mortgage#Amortization), i.e. 35 payments of 5998 and a final one of 206540 at the end of month 36.

"*With full amortization, the amortization schedule has been set so that the last periodical payment comprises the final portion of principal still due.*"

***Addendum***

With 36 payments of 5998 *and* a payment of 206540 at the end of month 36

```
s = 377100
m = 5998
b = 206540 + m = 212538
n = 35

∴ r = 0.00425237
```

The effective annual rate is `(1 + r)^12 - 1 = 5.2239 %`

Confiming with Excel

[image]

Comment: Thx again for the reply, Mr. Chris.  So the previous ans ~10% is incorrect?  Now is only 4.56819%?  Can I say that effective annual rate is APR?  Also, my repayment schedule is 36 payments of 5998, then last balloon payment is 206540.

Comment: And just to be clear, the 206540 is paid in month 36 along with the 36th payment of 5998?

Comment: after 36 mth of 5998, then one more final payment is 206540

Comment: With 36 payments of 5998 and a payment of 206540 at the end of month 36

Also deducting the downpayment from the principal<---377100 is already deducted the down pament from 419000 (ie 41900), so s = 377100

Comment: Then your effective rate is 5.2239% as shown in the addendum above.

Comment: Effective rate is 5.2339%? dropped from 11.06% to 5.2339%?  A bit confuse now.  Sorry, I am so stupid

Comment: If your loan is 419000 and downpayment is 10%, 41900, then you should start with `s = 377100` and the resulting effective rate is 5.2239%.  I will update the website screenshot to how it should be set up for this result.

Comment: Please see my comment below the screenshot

Answer (score 1):

For time value of money *calculator* computation:

PV = 377100

FV = 206540

N = 36

PMT = 5998 (note, your brand of calculator might want payment to be a negative number)

Calculate r

This gives you back the rate each month. Multiply by 12 for annual rate or (1+r)^12 for APR

Answer (score 1):

from this web site https://www.mortgagecalculator.org/calcs/balloon.php, it shows the effective interest rate is 11.02% (amount borrowed: 377100, long term in years: 3, Upfront payment: 41900, loan fees: 0, balloon payment at end:  206540, monthly payment:  5988.99)  How come the interest rate is much high that we calculated?  Please help.

***Editing the OP's post***

With `r = 0.00425237` per month, as calculated in the addendum.

Nominal annual interest rate, compounded monthly `12 r = 5.102844 %`

The results below are based on 36 payments of 5998 plus a final payment of 206540 at the end of month 36.  The total paid in month 36 is 212538.

[image]

Top and bottom of amortisation table.  Note the principal amount: 377100.

[image]

Comment: Thx Chris, but for "Amount Borrowed", should be 419000 or 377100? Since the house is 419000, and I need to pay 10% down payment, so the Amount borrowed, should be 377100, right? – north 27 secs ago

Comment: For the website calculator Amount Borrowed should be 419000 and Upfront Payment should be 41900.  The calculator automatically deducts the upfront payment from the amount borrowed to obtain the Principal: 377100, as shown in the Amortization Schedule.  Try setting the website calculator up as I have shown and check the amortization schedule.

Comment: Thx Chris!  Much appreciate for your help!  Now, is much clear.  Thanks a lot!